# Embedding *.chm help file in application itself (C# Winform)

Tags: c#, winforms, chm, user-manual

How can I include/embed .*chm help file in application itself (not as separate file in output)? Can it be placed in "Resources.resx" and read from there? I tried this method but it seems that it doesn't work...

Comment: Well, yes, you can embed it, but for the help viewer to be able to display it, wou will have to extract it into the file system somewhere before. What is your motivation?

Comment: @KlausGütter
I have a button in my program to display the help file but I want to prevent the help file from being modified by the user (or deleted from the installation folder)

Comment: I think you're prioritizing the wrong things. The help file will most like be completely _ignored_ by virtually all of the users of your program.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield
You may be right, it's not my priority. just thought the solution was simple, but it doesn't seem so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the chm in a resource is a bad idea and difficult to handle, deploy it as a plain file.

Changing and recompiling a CHM file is not an easy task without the associated project file (*.hhp). Therefore, the content is reasonably - but of course not completely - safe.

A user actually makes your software unusable by making changes to the installation path and help content. Updating the help topics must match the version of your app and is your responsibility.

If it meets your requirements you can think about a so-called web-based help. Upload  your help to a server and add a web browser control to your application.

See also:
[Best approach to implement Help feature in Windows Desktop Application - Restrict the App knowledge base to authorize access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63554389/best-approach-to-implement-help-feature-in-windows-desktop-application-restric)

Old stuff, but have a look at a sample for [Uncompressed help](https://www.help-info.de/en/h_start.htm) here too.